# How to solve matplotlib install issue on Python3.9.5?

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation

I'm not able to install matplotlib.
Windows 10, Python 3.9.5

C:\Windows\System32 is in PATH

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

This is the error after *conda install matplotlib*:

==============================

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::qt-5.12.9-h5909a2a_4'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::qt-5.12.9-h5909a2a_4
location of failed script: C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts\.qt-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:         1 file(s) copied.

stderr: 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

return code: 1
```

==================================

Comment: It seems the error message is quite clear : the console from which you try to install the package is unable to run the `chcp` command. See if this other post helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614437/unable-to-activate-conda-environment-as-chcp-and-cmd-is-not-recognized-as-in

Comment: @SpaceBurger Thanks. I've been trying to solve the issue repeatedly. Playing with path variables and anaconda prompt (regular user and admin), also removed some unused virtual environment. Didn't work. And, now it went through suddenly. No idea why. I've used the anaconda prompt as admin, and, probably not relevant, but I had two prompt windows open.

Comment: Usually you have to restart your terminal or even the computer to take into account a change in the environment variables, so it is possible one of them didn't register you changed your variables and the other was up to date because you opened it after making the changes. It doesn't explain why your system didn't have access to the command from the start, it could have been an issue with your installation location, user rights, and others things I don't know anything about... It's good that you solved it somehow though. You should check that it works even after restarting your computer though.