# Problem with installing scikit-learn / umap-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to install the packages umap-learn and scikit-learn, but it fails everytime.
I have already tried several things to solve this problem or these problems, for example running the application as an administrator and so on.

The terminal:

```py
(base) C:\Windows\System32>conda activate uma
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1555]
(uma) C:\Windows\System32>conda install -c conda-forge umap-learn 
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\ps4be\anaconda3\envs\uma

  added / updated specs:
    - umap-learn


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    ca-certificates-2023.5.7   |       h56e8100_0         145 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         145 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  colorama           conda-forge/noarch::colorama-0.4.6-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  intel-openmp       conda-forge/win-64::intel-openmp-2023.1.0-h57928b3_46319
  joblib             conda-forge/noarch::joblib-1.2.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  libblas            conda-forge/win-64::libblas-3.9.0-16_win64_mkl
  libcblas           conda-forge/win-64::libcblas-3.9.0-16_win64_mkl
  liblapack          conda-forge/win-64::liblapack-3.9.0-16_win64_mkl
  llvmlite           pkgs/main/win-64::llvmlite-0.39.1-py39h23ce68f_0
  m2w64-gcc-libgfor~ conda-forge/win-64::m2w64-gcc-libgfortran-5.3.0-6
  m2w64-gcc-libs     conda-forge/win-64::m2w64-gcc-libs-5.3.0-7
  m2w64-gcc-libs-co~ conda-forge/win-64::m2w64-gcc-libs-core-5.3.0-7
  m2w64-gmp          conda-forge/win-64::m2w64-gmp-6.1.0-2
  m2w64-libwinpthre~ conda-forge/win-64::m2w64-libwinpthread-git-5.0.0.4634.697f757-2
  mkl                conda-forge/win-64::mkl-2022.1.0-h6a75c08_874
  msys2-conda-epoch  conda-forge/win-64::msys2-conda-epoch-20160418-1
  numba              pkgs/main/win-64::numba-0.56.4-py39hf11a4ad_0
  numpy              conda-forge/win-64::numpy-1.22.3-py39h0948cea_2
  pynndescent        conda-forge/noarch::pynndescent-0.5.10-pyh1a96a4e_0
  python_abi         conda-forge/win-64::python_abi-3.9-2_cp39
  scikit-learn       pkgs/main/win-64::scikit-learn-1.2.2-py39hd77b12b_0
  scipy              conda-forge/win-64::scipy-1.8.1-py39h5567194_2
  tbb                pkgs/main/win-64::tbb-2021.8.0-h59b6b97_0
  threadpoolctl      conda-forge/noarch::threadpoolctl-3.1.0-pyh8a188c0_0
  tqdm               conda-forge/noarch::tqdm-4.65.0-pyhd8ed1ab_1
  umap-learn         conda-forge/win-64::umap-learn-0.5.3-py39hcbf5309_0
  zlib               conda-forge/win-64::zlib-1.2.11-h8d14728_1011

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2023.01.10~ --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2023.5.7-h56e8100_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
                                                                                                                                                           
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: / 

    Windows 64-bit packages of scikit-learn can be accelerated using scikit-learn-intelex.
    More details are available here: https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex

    For example:

        $ conda install scikit-learn-intelex
        $ python -m sklearnex my_application.py


done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(740): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::scikit-learn-1.2.2-py39hd77b12b_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::scikit-learn-1.2.2-py39hd77b12b_0
location of failed script: C:\Users\ps4be\anaconda3\envs\uma\Scripts\.scikit-learn-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==


    Windows 64-bit packages of scikit-learn can be accelerated using scikit-learn-intelex.
    More details are available here: https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex

    For example:

        $ conda install scikit-learn-intelex
        $ python -m sklearnex my_application.py


==> script output <==
stdout: subdir: win-64

stderr: 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

return code: 1

()
```

So two errors:

```py
==> script output <==
stdout: subdir: win-64

stderr: 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

return code: 1
```

and

```py
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(740): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::scikit-learn-1.2.2-py39hd77b12b_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done
```

The paths etc:

[The paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxVRn.png)

[The paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGU9f.png)

Comment: watch here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614437/unable-to-activate-conda-environment-as-chcp-and-cmd-is-not-recognized-as-in